# IE Not Applying Styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, stylesheet

I am compiling several stylesheets into one min stylesheet in a staging environment  The styles are applied locally in IE where each stylesheet is separate, but they are not being applied in the staging environment in IE where the stylesheets are compiled into one min stylesheet.  I have run the stylesheets through a CSS validator and have gone through each stylesheet and corrected any syntax errors that I found.  I don't necessarily need to know how to solve the problem, I mainly want to know where the problem exists.  The IE developer tools aren't giving me any feedback related to the problem of styles not being applied.

Here is a link to the login page in the staging environment: https://s-app.joinhere.com/manage/sessions/new.  The styles are in the stylesheet, they just aren't being applied in IE.  Here's a link to the compiled min stylesheet: https://staging.joinhere.com/assets/manage-d4f70cefc93b170b5f2a04509db697c8.css

Thanks!

Comment: I could only check it in IE 10 and it looked fine to me. Are there any particular styles that your IE did not apply... or was it the whole css file?

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue, but have yet to resolve it.  In IE9's CSS developer tool it shows that it's applying a particular color to a node, but it clearly is not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your page, and it works fine in Chrome.  However it looks weird in IE9, as if the CSS styles are not being applied, just as you described.  For example, the style `body#manage-sessions #main_container #login_container` is not getting applied.  I looked at the css tab in the developer tools, and it turns out the style is not even there, which explains how it is not working.  To find out why, I used the networks inspector from the developer tool and examined the response when IE9 is downloading the css, and the style `body#manage-sessions #main_container #login_container` is indeed in the response.  This lead me to believe that there must be some limit on the max css file size for IE.  It appears that this is indeed the case as described [here](http://neopatel.blogspot.com/2010/07/ie-css-size-limit.html).  Apparently IE simply ignores additional styles if the css file gets past a certain size.  So this explains why everything works when the css files are separate, and why things fall apart after you combine them.  To solve the problem try splitting up your large css file into 2 or more smaller ones that fall under the IE limit, and see if this corrects the problem.

Comment: Turns out, in IE only the first 288kb in a file will be read and processed. Any CSS after 288kb will be ignored. We're at about 450 right now.  I'm going to have to restructure the styles to get below 288.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: @ErikVanLankvelt Yes you can always count on IE to give you lame problems like this.  Anyway if my answer helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it looks like the limit was a bit lower when I tried it, so I was surprised when it didn't work at first. Got the size down to 230K and it still didn't work. Ultimately, it parsed the whole file at 182 no problem. What an annoying issue. I'll add this to my long list of IE battle scars.

Comment: Correction. It still wasn't working at 280. At 148 it all seems to be getting included.

Comment: Something that might be relevant: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/05/14/stylesheet-limits-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your personal setup, however, anything < IE 10 can only handle 32 individual stylesheets, anything after will still show up in the Dev tools like its working but rest assured, the 33 stylesheet is committed to a life of silent failure.